# Capybara: Screenshots with chrome are randomly dark

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, ui-testing

in our ui testing with capybara we are using chrome and chrome headless, since PhantomJS is deprecated.

We compare Screenshots to see if the page is looking exactly how it should look like. That works pretty fine, but there is a randomness, how chrome takes the screenshot. Sometimes the screenshots are pretty dark, which makes the test fail at the end. Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1):

The awesome solution is, to put a delay before the method for taking a screenshot. A delay of 1 second cares for a bright screenshot. I still can not explain why exactly this is necessary.

Comment: You probably have an animation on the page that fades it in to view

Comment: Had the Idea too in the last days. Do you know a way to tell Capybara to wait until the animation is finished?